# Reuse Flexformvalue in foreign_table_where

Tags: typo3, extbase

After chosen a group, I want to visible all categories matching these groups. Is this possible?

```
<settings.flexform.categorygroups>
                    <TCEforms>
                        <label>Category</label>
                        <displayCond>FIELD:switchableControllerActions:=:Job->list</displayCond>
                        <config>
                            <type>select</type>
                            <foreign_table>tx_ext_domain_model_jobcategorygroup</foreign_table>
                            <minitems>1</minitems>
                            <maxitems>99</maxitems>
                            <size>4</size>
                        </config>
                    </TCEforms>
                </settings.flexform.categorygroups>


<settings.flexform.categories>
                    <TCEforms>
                        <label>Category</label>
                        <displayCond>FIELD:settings.flexform.categorygroups:REQ:true</displayCond>
                        <config>
                            <type>select</type>
                            <foreign_table>tx_ext_domain_model_jobcategory</foreign_table>
                            <foreign_table_where>AND tx_ext_domain_model_jobcategory.job_category_group IN (###jobcategory###)</foreign_table_where>
                            <minitems>1</minitems>
                            <maxitems>99</maxitems>
                            <size>4</size>
                        </config>
                    </TCEforms>
                </settings.flexform.categories>
```

How to fill this 'IN'?

Answer (score 0):

In the TCA there are some markers for this kind of stuff. Not sure if it already works for Flexforms too. 
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Select/Index.html#foreign-table-where